# Auto reaction message discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I make an auto message code which runs every 2.5 hours in a specific channel with the ID: 731634178029912096?

(I have no knowledge of discord.js)

Below is the code currently in the bot:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "view all commands and their description",
    run: async (message, args) => {

        const { commands } = require("../selfbot.js")
        const { prefix } = require("../config.json")

        let msg = ""

        for (command of commands.keys()) {
            msg = msg + prefix + "**" + command + "** " + commands.get(command).description + "\n"
        }

        await message.edit(msg).then(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                message.delete().catch()
            }, 10000)
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is doing the `setTimeout();` in the command file. which will only be read when the command is called. This is what you should be doing:

```
//index.js
var helpMessage = "whatever is in the message";
const helpChannel = client.channels.cache.get(731634178029912096);
const sendMessage = setInterval(() => helpChannel.send(helpMessage), 9000000); //9000000 = milliseconds in 2.5 hours
```

Note: Using a channel ID will only work for **that specific channel** in that server.